# Spring:bind with checkbox

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

In the code below `testData` is an `HashMap`. I am trying to bind checkbox with `spring:bind` tag.
I am getting syntax errors on spring:bind. Could you tell me what is the issue in my code?

```
<c:forEach items="${testData}" var="test" varStatus="loopStatus"> 
     <spring:bind path="${testData[${loopStatus.index}]}.selected"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="_${status.expression}"> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="${status.expression}" value="true"> 
            <c:if test="${status.value}">checked</c:if> 
     </spring:bind> 
   </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you have another syntax error but start by changing this:

```
<spring:bind path="${testData[${loopStatus.index}]}.selected">
```

for

```
<spring:bind path="${testData[loopStatus.index]}.selected">
```

Answer (score 0):

The path in your spring:bind tag is probably wrong. I can't tell you the correct path as you haven't described the object you're binding to.

You may want to use the [form:checkbox](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-formtaglib-checkboxtag) tag instead of spring bind.

Comment: @skaffman:testData is the object of typeHashMap here ,command name is search.

Answer (score 0):

First, in Expression Language, `${` starts your expression and `}` ends it.  You don't need to nest them or anything, so `${testData[${loopStatus.index}]}` is your syntax error, and `.selected` is outside of your expression, so that should just be: `${testData[loopStatus.index].selected}`.

Now, in `forEach`, your `var` attribute determines the name of the variable that holds the current item.  So you rarely need to use `varStatus`.  You can just have your test as `${test.selected}`.

Finally, your `checked` attribute is outside of your checkbox input element!

So:

```
<c:forEach items="${testData}" var="test"> 
   <spring:bind path="${test.selected}"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="_${status.expression}"> 
      <input type="checkbox" name="${status.expression}" value="true" <c:if test="${status.value}">checked</c:if>>
   </spring:bind> 
</c:forEach>
```

(not sure you ever need the hidden field, we're not using one for any of our checkboxes).